# Jenkins-x 3 deployment issues on EKS with Terraform

Tags: jenkins-x, jenkins-x-3

I am new to Jenkins-x and having trouble with the installation on EKS using Secrets Manager with Terraform installation approach. Seeing these errors. Any help is really appreciated.
I did make a dummy commit to our internal bitbucket cluster repo(jx3-eks-asm) and still seeing same errors, I believe it's because the boot pods are failing as well. Here are the errors from health status command.

There were bunch of other issues too but was able to resolve by making local changes to kuberhealthy and other helm chart versions. I have verified that we have terraform, aws-cli, aws-iam-authenticator, and wget as mentioned in the prerequisites section. Noticed that none of the health commands work if kuberhealthy is disabled and it appears that there are bunch of issues with that Helm chart and CRDs installation. Its using an old version of the chart, so I updated to 0.0.90 or similar to fix another issue but now seeing this.

Error from one of boot pods in the jx-git-operator ns:

```
error validating "config-root/namespaces/jx/jx-kh-check-health-checks-jx/jx-bot-token-kuberhealthycheck.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(KuberhealthyCheck.spec.podSpec.containers[0]): unknown field "restartPolicy" in io.github.comcast.v1.KuberhealthyCheck.spec.podSpec.containers; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "config-root/namespaces/jx/jx-kh-check-health-checks-jx/jx-webhook-events-kuberhealthycheck.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(KuberhealthyCheck.spec.podSpec.containers[0]): unknown field "restartPolicy" in io.github.comcast.v1.KuberhealthyCheck.spec.podSpec.containers; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
error validating "config-root/namespaces/jx/jx-kh-check-health-checks-jx/jx-webhook-kuberhealthycheck.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(KuberhealthyCheck.spec.podSpec.containers[0]): unknown field "restartPolicy" in io.github.comcast.v1.KuberhealthyCheck.spec.podSpec.containers; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
make[1]: Leaving directory '/workspace/source'
make[1]: *** [versionStream/src/Makefile.mk:324: kubectl-apply] Error 1
error: failed to regenerate: failed to regenerate phase 1: failed to run 'make regen-phase-1 NEW_CLUSTER=false' command in directory '.', output: ''
make: *** [versionStream/src/Makefile.mk:269: regen-check] Error 1
```

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23+", GitVersion:"v1.23.13-eks-fb459a0", GitCommit:"55bd5d5cb7d32bc35e4e050f536181196fb8c6f7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-10-24T20:38:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24+", GitVersion:"v1.24.13-eks-0a21954", GitCommit:"6305d65c340554ad8b4d7a5f21391c9fa34932cb", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-04-15T00:33:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
jx health status -A
                          NAME                     NAMESPACE                        STATUSERROR MESSAGE
                     daemonset                  kuberhealthy                   OK
                    deployment                  kuberhealthy                   OK
           dns-status-internal                  kuberhealthy                   OK
                    jx-install               jx-git-operator                         ERRORlatest boot job jx-boot-1997a686-37fb-4704-af81-8505a7518877 has been running for more than 30m0s, it could be stuck
                                                                                          latest boot job jx-boot-1997a686-37fb-4704-af81-8505a7518877 has a failed run
                 jx-pod-status                  kuberhealthy                         ERRORpod: jenkins-x-chartmuseum-6cd76fd747-4hwrc in namespace: jx is in pod status phase Pending
                                                                                          pod: jx-build-controller-b6bdc5b6d-ch2xh in namespace: jx is in pod status phase Pending
                                                                                          pod: jx-pipelines-visualizer-7b685f9c79-bdx5k in namespace: jx is in pod status phase Pending
                                                                                          pod: lighthouse-foghorn-cff4fd4f5-r76kr in namespace: jx is in pod status phase Pending
                                                                                          pod: lighthouse-keeper-57dfddb5f9-plfjn in namespace: jx is in pod status phase Pending
                                                                                          pod: lighthouse-webhooks-85f985b664-9wdgx in namespace: jx is in pod status phase Pending
                                                                                          pod: nexus-nexus-776c96f565-vxp42 in namespace: jx is in pod status phase Pending
                    jx-secrets                  kuberhealthy                         ERRORERROR, Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
                                                                                          ERROR, Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
                                                                                          ERROR, Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
                                                                                          ERROR, Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
                                                                                          ERROR, Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
                                                                                          ERROR, Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
                                                                                          ERROR, Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.
```

```
jx secret verify
SECRET                                       STATUS
jx-production/tekton-container-registry-auth key tekton-container-registry-auth missing properties: .dockerconfigjson
jx-staging/tekton-container-registry-auth    key tekton-container-registry-auth missing properties: .dockerconfigjson
jx/jenkins-maven-settings                    key jx-maven-settings missing properties: settingsXml, securityXml
jx/jenkins-x-chartmuseum                     valid: jx-admin-user/BASIC_AUTH_PASS, jx-admin-user/BASIC_AUTH_USER
jx/jx-basic-auth-htpasswd                    key jx-basic-auth-htpasswd missing properties: token
jx/jx-basic-auth-user-password               valid: jx-basic-auth-user/password, jx-basic-auth-user/username
jx/lighthouse-oauth-token                    key lighthouse-oauth missing properties: token
jx/nexus                                     valid: jx-admin-user/password
jx/tekton-container-registry-auth            key tekton-container-registry-auth missing properties: .dockerconfigjson
jx/tekton-git                                key jx-pipeline-user missing properties: token, username
```